# ¿Como cargar una tabla de mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mysqli, postgresql

¿Buenos dias, soy nuevo en php, necesito cargar una tabla completa que esta en mi base de datos mysql y mostrarla como tabla con su cabecera y todo en mi pagina web, si me pudieran ayudar, gracias?

Comment: Que has Investigado y/o intentado hacer?

Comment: bueno yo logre hacer lo mismo con tablas que tengo en otra base de datos en postgresql, pero cuando intento usar las funciones de php para mysql q se parecen a las de postgre no funcionan de la misma manera.

Comment: la pagina que tengo q crear es bastante sencilla solo tengo que mostrar las tablas que estan almacenadas en la base de datos, las cosultas las hago en sql, pero la pagina tiene que ser capaz de coger y cargarme cualquier tabla con cabeceras incluidas no tener yo que  teclearle las cabeceras en el codigo, como he visto en ejemplos aqui, todo tiene que ser automatico, porque son tablas muy grandes y son bastantes

Comment: Solo es el problema con tu consulta?? lo demás si funciona?? Que consulta quieres realizar en MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

En principio, creo que deberías utilizar PDO, eso si estas utilizando php plano. Si utilizas algún framework tipo Laravel las cosas cambian un poco pero son más fáciles.

En principio el ejemplo podría ser así:

```
<?php
function getFruit($conn) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['color'] . "\t";
        print $row['calories'] . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Lo puedes encontrar [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php), yo te sugeriría revisar la documentación de PDO en el siguiente [link](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php).

Espero haber podido ayudarte.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias, si me ayudaste